How do I find the solution to this polynomial function?
The problem:
Find the roots of the polynomial. If a root is repeated, give its multiplicity. Also, write each polynomial as a product of linear factors.
$x^6 - 3x^4 + 3x^2 - 1 = 0$
The answer:
roots $1$ (triple) and $-1$ (triple); $(x-1)^3(x+1)^3$
My question:
What's the simple and recommended way to solve this? I started off using the rational zero theorem to find the root $1$ and then divided the whole polynomial function by the factor $(x-1)$ but soon realized my chosen method was all too time consuming. Surely there must be an easier way to reach the answer?

Note that $(y-1)^3=y^3-3y^2+3y-1$.

Put x^2 = t then it reduces to a cubic equation

This question is similar to: How to factor $r^6 -3r^4 +3r^2 - 1 = 0$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search.

Observe all the powers of $x$ are multiples of an integer.  Here, that integer is $2$, so make the substitution $x^2 \mapsto u$.
$$  u^3 - 3u^2 + 3u - 1 = 0  $$
The rational root theorem will tell you to try $\pm 1$ and, as you already know, $u = 1$ is a root and is the only rational root (ignoring multiplicities).  So check to see if this is the only root by cubing it.  (If you need an additional reason, Descartes' rule of signs says there are three or one positive real roots and the rational root theorem says the only rational one is at $1$, so hope there are three and they're all $1$.)
$$  (u-1)^3 = u^3 - 3u^2 + 3u - 1  $$
So it is.  Then we started with
$$ (u-1)^3 = (x^2 -1)^3 = (x-1)^3(x+1)^3  $$
